# sbt to include unmanagedJars while publishing in build.sbt

Tags: sbt, publishing

How to include few unmanagedJars as dependecies while publishing, How to update publishingConfigaration in sbt to control dependnecy pom file.

Comment: We can't, easiest way is to publish those jars manually using maven/ivy or any other tool to your artifactory or repository and add those jars in sbt libraryDependencies...